# Camera2 SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE values for specific resolution / mode

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have been working around camera2 android API to build my new application, but I've been facing some issues that I can't resolve reading the official docs or other questions here in SO or other sites.

I need to know the device camera sensitivity range, which can be obtained using the `SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE` from camera characteristics ([as documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics)). I can manage without issues when the device cannot offer this information, but I've encountered that this range is always the same for the same `cameraId`; but checking the value at the `CaptureCallback` for the [`SENSOR_SENSITIVITY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) parameter, there are many devices where the values never go even near of the range limit (for instance, in a Motorola One Vision it never returns more than 1427, when its theoretical value - the upper range value for `SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE` - is 3200)

I have made many tests, and have checked that the final value for it depends on scan resolution, frame rate, and many other things (for instance, limiting the FPS to 10 per second, the value for `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` is never over 712).

Is there any method in order to get the real range for the current `CameraCaptureSession` or `CaptureRequest`? Or some way to translate to the original `SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE` the values returned at `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY`, in order to get a homogenous functioning function to analyze the values.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, as I'm absolutely blocked with this.

Comment: have you found any answer for this? it is very interesting for me

Comment: No, I can't find anything else about this; tried to understand how Android manages this ranges but can't find an answer; it will be really cool to find an answer to this